# How to use js server functions as part of osql

Tags: orientdb

I have a js function with rids as parameter (see "Execute" on screenshot), it works:

[image]

I try to use this function with result of subquery in osql:

```
select testFunction(select @rid from User where someField < 365)
```

And it gives me `Error parsing query` of course.

How to use function as part of osql in that case?

Comment: I think it doesn't work because with "select @rid from User where someField < 365" you get a list and not a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
select testFunction(@this.@rid) from User where someField < 365
```

in this way it's going to call the function every time it found a record passing that single record to the function and so on for every result of the `select from User where someField < 365`

Hope it helps!
Ivan